# How can I get the content path for URL meta tags?

Tags: next.js, seo, meta-tags

I'm not crazy experiences with meta tags, but to my knowledge, meta tags like `og:url` or `twitter:url` help platforms like twitter or facebook to kind of cache the result and not have to query the page with every use again.

Hence I'm trying to get the URL for every page, including dynamic pages, like this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content={router.asPath} />
```

This obviously results in `/contact` or `/news/1` - I assume this is a problem (is it though?), so how do I include the whole URL? Something like `window.location.href` but server side?

Comment: Is your app deployed on several different domains? Or why can't you just prepend the base path of the url?

Comment: My app is indeed deployed on several domains. The solution I'm going for is to add an env variable with the current domain and concat the path to my page on the end of this.

Answer (score 2):

As there is no `window` object server side, you would have to check for it and do it client side.

### Option 1

Check for the `window`:

```
<meta property="og:url" content={window ? window.location.href : "https://somehardcoded.url"} />
```

### Option 2

Use the `useEffect` hook as it runs only client side:

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState("https://somehardcoded.url")
useEffect(() => {
  setUrl(window.location.href);
});

<meta property="og:url" content={url} />
```

Comment: will it affect SEO if url is set with client side Javascript?